# how do i print the double variable inside or outside the for loop

Tags: c++

I am doing a project on hotel occupancy but I am having a difficulty in printing the `double` variable. I need to know how to display the `double` variable using `setprecision`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numfloors=0; //for number of floors
    int numrooms=0; //for number of rooms per floor
    int numoccipied=0; //for rooms that are occupied
    int TRooms=0; //for total rooms in hotel
    int TOcuppied=0; //for total rooms occupied in the hotel
    int TUnoccupied=0; //for unoccupied rooms in the hotel
    double occupancy=0; //for persentage occupancy

    cout<<"Enter the number of floors in the hotel"
        <<"\nNote: please do not write value less than 1: ";
    cin>>numfloors;

    for(int floor=1; floor<=numfloors; floor++) //loop starts
    {
        cout<<"how many rooms are there in no."<<floor<<"floor?\n"; //ask user to for number of rooms per floor
        cin>>numrooms;

        TRooms+= numrooms; //total rooms in each floor will add and store in Trooms
        cout<<"how many rooms are ocupied?\n";  //ask user to put number of occupied rooms
        cin>>numoccipied;
        TOcuppied+=numoccipied; //number of rooms occupied per floor is added 
        TUnoccupied=TRooms-TOcuppied; //stores all unoccupied rooms
        occupancy=(TOcuppied)/TRooms; //store persentage occupancy 

        cout<<"\n\nThe Hotel has "<<TRooms<<"rooms\n";
        cout<<"from which "<<TOcuppied<< " rooms are occupied,\n";
        cout<<"and "<<TUnoccupied<<" are Unoccupied.\n ";
    }
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    cout<<"\n\nOccupancy Rate: "<<occupancy*100<<"% \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before the `for` loop, you can use `cout << occupancy << endl;`.  After the `for` loop, you can use `cout << occupancy << endl;`

Comment: An example of [`setprecision` at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).  Note the spelling, the identifier is all lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a beginner so I'll list some problems with your code:

1. When dividing two integers, the result is also an integer. So, in integral division, 4/10 is 0. This line, therefore, always produces zero:

   ```
   occupancy=(TOcuppied)/TRooms;
   ```

   Instead use:

   ```
   occupancy=(TOcuppied)/(double)TRooms;
   ```
2. The settings for `cout` must obviously all come BEFORE the input. So first send the settings:

   ```
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   cout << occupancy*100;
   ```

   Of course, you can put it on one line:

   ```
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1)<< occupancy*100;
   ```
3. You're allowing some kinds of invalid output. Since yours look a lot like homework assignment, you might need to sanitize those. One is that you allow one to enter more occupied rooms than available:

   ```
   how many rooms are there in no.1floor?
   10
   how many rooms are ocupied?
   20

   The Hotel has 10rooms
   from which 20 rooms are occupied,
   and -10 are Unoccupied.

   Occupancy Rate: 200.00%
   ```

   So remember to check that input:

   ```
   if(numoccipied>numrooms) {
       // do something, such as asking the user to enter correct value
   }
   ```

   Similarly, you should prevent user from entering less than 1 floor:

   ```
   if(numfloors<1)
       return 0;
   ```